# Access export table to Excel trims blank spaces

Tags: excel, ms-access

let's say I have an Access Database and I want to copy one table into an Excel File and let's also assume this table is to large for copy and pasting. So I normally used the Access "export table to Excel" function which worked quite well so far.

Now for some reason we now have an attribute where some entries contain blank spaces in the end and we want to keep those blank spaces (don't ask why...). Copy pasting in the Excel works fine, but if you start the export function (because the table is too big for copying) those blank spaces get **trimmed**, which I would like to avoid.

Does anybody have an Idea on how to work around that?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you clarify further what the data looks like in Access, and when it is exported to Excel and what you would like it to look like in Excel?  For example by blank spaces, do you mean a zero length string, or 1 or more spaces?

Comment: Of course! I have string entries that look kind of like this: 'ABCdefc   /      ' and after exporting to Excel they are reduced to 'ABCdefc   /'. So what happens ist, the last blank space is being cut off, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I see the same behavior, when I tested this (exporting to Excel either with formatting and layout, or without).  I don't know how to change this behavior in Access, but as a workaround, how about exporting to text (e.g. tab separated), and then importing the text to Excel?  By the way, it seems that when entering text in the Access GUI trailing spaces are trimmed, so Access seems to be assuming in general that trailing spaces are mistaken entries.